# My barcode scanner on an android studio project will not register barcode

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am trying to get the barcode scanner to work on an android studio project. It calls up the barcode scanner but does not read the barcode (though when I call the app up separately there is no issue). Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
Here's the specific barcode part:

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.scan_button) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            previewBtn.setTag(scanContent);
```

Please see main activity below (apologies for the mess, I've included lots of stuff I want to do after).

```
package com.example.barry.bookcataloguev3;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Button scanBtn,previewBtn,linkBtn;
private TextView authorText, titleText, descriptionText, dateText, ratingCountText;
private LinearLayout starLayout;
private ImageView thumbView;
private ImageView[] starViews;
private Bitmap thumbImg;
//private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    //formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    //contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    previewBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.preview_btn);
    previewBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    previewBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    linkBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.link_btn);
    linkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linkBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    authorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.book_author);
    titleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.book_title);
    descriptionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.book_description);
    dateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.book_date);
    starLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.star_layout);
    ratingCountText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.book_rating_count);
    thumbView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb);
    starViews=new ImageView[5];
    for(int s=0; s<starViews.length; s++){
        starViews[s]=new ImageView(this);
    }
    starViews=new ImageView[5];
    for(int s=0; s<starViews.length; s++){
        starViews[s]=new ImageView(this);
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        authorText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("author"));
        titleText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
        descriptionText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("description"));
        dateText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("date"));
        ratingCountText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ratings"));
        int numStars = savedInstanceState.getInt("stars");//zero if null
        for(int s=0; s<numStars; s++){
            starViews[s].setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
            starLayout.addView(starViews[s]);
        }
        starLayout.setTag(numStars);
        thumbImg = (Bitmap)savedInstanceState.getParcelable("thumbPic");
        thumbView.setImageBitmap(thumbImg);
        previewBtn.setTag(savedInstanceState.getString("isbn"));

        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isEmbed")) previewBtn.setEnabled(true);
        else previewBtn.setEnabled(false);
        if(savedInstanceState.getInt("isLink")==View.VISIBLE) linkBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else linkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        previewBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void onClick(View view){
    if(view.getId()==R.id.scan_button) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        //if(view.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.link_btn){
        //get the url tag
        String tag = (String)view.getTag();
        //launch the url
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(tag));
        startActivity(webIntent);
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.preview_btn){
        String tag = (String)view.getTag();
        //launch preview
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmbeddedBook.class);
        intent.putExtra("isbn", tag);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
        //IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        //scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    //}
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            previewBtn.setTag(scanContent);
            if(scanContent!=null && scanFormat!=null && scanFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("EAN_13")){
                //book search
                String bookSearchString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?"+
                        "q=isbn:"+scanContent+"&key=AIzaSyDnc2MSK760g6NiKt65dI96lRSsVdjo4BM";
                new GetBookInfo().execute(bookSearchString);
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Not a valid scan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            Log.v("SCAN", "content: "+scanContent+" - format: "+scanFormat);
            //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            //contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    /*retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }*/
}

private class GetBookInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //fetch book info
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... bookURLs) {
        //request book info
        StringBuilder bookBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String bookSearchURL : bookURLs) {
            //search urls
            HttpClient bookClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpGet bookGet = new HttpGet(bookSearchURL);
                HttpResponse bookResponse = bookClient.execute(bookGet);
                StatusLine bookSearchStatus = bookResponse.getStatusLine();
                if (bookSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    //we have a result
                    HttpEntity bookEntity = bookResponse.getEntity();
                    InputStream bookContent = bookEntity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader bookInput = new InputStreamReader(bookContent);
                    BufferedReader bookReader = new BufferedReader(bookInput);
                    String lineIn;
                    while ((lineIn = bookReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        bookBuilder.append(lineIn);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        return bookBuilder.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //parse search results
        try{
            //parse results
            previewBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray bookArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("items");
            JSONObject bookObject = bookArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject volumeObject = bookObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            try{ titleText.setText("TITLE: "+volumeObject.getString("title")); }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                titleText.setText("");
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringBuilder authorBuild = new StringBuilder("");
            try{
                JSONArray authorArray = volumeObject.getJSONArray("authors");
                for(int a=0; a<authorArray.length(); a++){
                    if(a>0) authorBuild.append(", ");
                    authorBuild.append(authorArray.getString(a));
                }
                authorText.setText("AUTHOR(S): "+authorBuild.toString());
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                authorText.setText("");
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{ dateText.setText("PUBLISHED: " + volumeObject.getString("publishedDate")); }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                dateText.setText("");
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{ descriptionText.setText("DESCRIPTION: "+volumeObject.getString("description")); }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                descriptionText.setText("");
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                //set stars
                double decNumStars = Double.parseDouble(volumeObject.getString("averageRating"));
                int numStars = (int)decNumStars;
                starLayout.setTag(numStars);
                starLayout.removeAllViews();
                for(int s=0; s<numStars; s++){
                    starViews[s].setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    starLayout.addView(starViews[s]);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                starLayout.removeAllViews();
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ratingCountText.setText(" - " + volumeObject.getString("ratingsCount") + " ratings"); }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                ratingCountText.setText("");
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                boolean isEmbeddable = Boolean.parseBoolean
                        (bookObject.getJSONObject("accessInfo").getString("embeddable"));
                if(isEmbeddable) previewBtn.setEnabled(true);
                else previewBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                previewBtn.setEnabled(false);
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                linkBtn.setTag(volumeObject.getString("infoLink"));
                linkBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                linkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                JSONObject imageInfo = volumeObject.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                new GetBookThumb().execute(imageInfo.getString("smallThumbnail"));
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                thumbView.setImageBitmap(null);
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //no result
            e.printStackTrace();
            titleText.setText("NOT FOUND");
            authorText.setText("");
            descriptionText.setText("");
            dateText.setText("");
            starLayout.removeAllViews();
            ratingCountText.setText("");
            thumbView.setImageBitmap(null);
            previewBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

private class GetBookThumb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //get thumbnail
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... thumbURLs) {
        //attempt to download image
        try{
            //try to download
            URL thumbURL = new URL(thumbURLs[0]);
            URLConnection thumbConn = thumbURL.openConnection();
            thumbConn.connect();
            InputStream thumbIn = thumbConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream thumbBuff = new BufferedInputStream(thumbIn);
            thumbImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(thumbBuff);
            thumbBuff.close();
            thumbIn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedBundle) {
    savedBundle.putString("title", ""+titleText.getText());
    savedBundle.putString("author", ""+authorText.getText());
    savedBundle.putString("description", ""+descriptionText.getText());
    savedBundle.putString("date", ""+dateText.getText());
    savedBundle.putString("ratings", ""+ratingCountText.getText());
    savedBundle.putParcelable("thumbPic", thumbImg);
    if(starLayout.getTag()!=null)
        savedBundle.putInt("stars", Integer.parseInt(starLayout.getTag().toString()));
    savedBundle.putBoolean("isEmbed", previewBtn.isEnabled());
    savedBundle.putInt("isLink", linkBtn.getVisibility());
    if(previewBtn.getTag()!=null)
        savedBundle.putString("isbn", previewBtn.getTag().toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your whole `MainActivity` code? I've tried developing app with barcode as well and I was able to get the result by getting it from `intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");`, which in your code, is the `scanContent`. But to make sure, I need to see more of your codes.

Comment: Thanks for looking! I've included the full code above.